# Xcode C++ socket programming parse Issue Expected expression

Tags: c++, xcode, sockets

I'm a newbie to socket programming and I'm trying to write a fork() function to enable the client to receive information sent by each four servers.

This is piece of the code I wrote, but it says parse Issue Expected expression.
I checked everything, used the "show invisible' but didn't work, the problem persist.

```
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        close(tcp_socket);
        char buffer[255]={0};
        int bytes_num;
        char serID[] = "0";
        //std::string serID = "0";
       // char serID[7] = "0";
        while(true)
        {
            //recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
            bytes_num = recv(tcp_socket2,buffer,254,0);
            if(bytes_num == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            if(serID[] == "0")---------------->problem here
            {
                serID[]= buffer[0];
            }
            printf("serverID %s\n", serID);

            if(serID[]=="serverA")---------------->problem here
            {
                 //printf("NOW files!\n");
                strcpy(str_file1[msg_num1],buffer);
                msg_num1++;
            }
            if(serID[]=="serverB")---------------->problem here
            {
                strcpy(str_file2[msg_num2],buffer);
                msg_num2++;
            }
            if(serID[]=="serverC")---------------->problem here
            {
                strcpy(str_file3[msg_num3],buffer);
                msg_num3++;
            }
            if(serID[]=="serverD")---------------->problem here
            {
                strcpy(str_file4[msg_num4],buffer);
                msg_num4++;
            }

            memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        }


        if((serID[]=="serverA"))---------------->problem here
        {
            pf_file1 = fopen("rcvd_fileA.txt","w");
            for(int i=0; i< msg_num1;i++)
            {
                 //printf("now we read files!\n");
                fprintf(pf_file1,"%s\n",str_file1[i]);
            }
            fclose(pf_file1);
        }
        if((serID[]=="serverB"))---------------->problem here
        {
            pf_file2 = fopen("rcvd_fileB.txt","w");
            for(int i=0; i< msg_num2;i++)
            {
                fprintf(pf_file2,"%s\n",str_file2[i]);
            }
            fclose(pf_file2);
        }
        if((serID[]=="serverC"))---------------->problem here
        {
            pf_file3 = fopen("rcvd_fileC.txt","w");
            for(int i=0; i< msg_num3;i++)
            {
                fprintf(pf_file3,"%s\n",str_file3[i]);
            }
            fclose(pf_file3);
        }
        if((serID[]=="serverD"))---------------->problem here
        {
            pf_file4 = fopen("rcvd_fileD.txt","w");
            for(int i=0; i< msg_num4;i++)
            {
                fprintf(pf_file4,"%s\n",str_file4[i]);
            }
            fclose(pf_file4);
        }

        printf("The Client receives neighbor information from the Server %s with TCP port number %d and IP address %s \n",serID.c_str(),ntohs(sin.sin_port), ipstr);

        close(tcp_socket2);

        // printf("The Server %c has the following neighbor information: \n",serverID);

        return 0;
    }
```

////////////////////
    I would really appreciate any one could help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `serID` should be a `char`, not a `char []`.

Comment: `if(serID == "0") { serID = buffer[0] }`

Comment: But the problem is, I also create 4 threads in the main function on server side. When they are sending the files, I also need to send some ID to let the client know which file belongs to which server. How could I achieve that??

Comment: The key now I'm using is a type char[]                                                      char id0[] = "serverA";
    char id1[] = "serverB";
    char id2[] = "serverC";
    char id3[] = "serverD";